# how to align message and icon in messagedialog?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

```
private void ErrMsg( final String message ) {
        Shell shell = new Shell(Display.getDefault(), SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        final MessageDialog dialog =
            new MessageDialog(shell, "Hello", null, "warning message is there", MessageDialog.WARNING, new String[] {
                JFaceResources.getString(IDialogLabelKeys.OK_LABEL_KEY)
            }, 1);
        new ECPDialogExecutor(dialog) {
            @Override
            public void handleResult( final int theCodeResult ) {
            }
        } .execute();
    }
```

The above method gives message dialog but icon and message not aligned.
Can we make icon and message aligned in same row?

Sorry,as image of messagedialog not possible to add due to some error.

Thanks in Advance..!!

Comment: It would help to also include the import statements and the code that calls this `ErrMsg()` method

Comment: Actually in any messagedialog if we provide icon and message then at time of pop-up messagedialog not show icon and message in alignment.

Comment: I added \n before message which i want with icon. now it gives me little bit aligned message and icon.